# Passing ArrayList from Java to PHP webservice

Tags: java, php, web-services

I have a java program that contains a username and passwords (strings) and an ArrayList of objects with 4 attributes (long, int, int int) and I want to pass these 3 things to a WebService (that I have yet to make). My host is Bluehost and it's a shared server so I won't have Java available server side it will need to be in PHP.

What is the best way of connecting to the webservice and passing this into php?

EDIT.

OK so I now have something like this:

```
public void upload(ArrayList<MyObject> myList) throws Exception{

    //HTTP POST Service
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("www.myHost.com")
        .setPath("/myWebservice.php")
        .setUserInfo(userID, password)
        .build();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I'm still not sure how I can pass the ArrayList in a way that I'll be able to receive and split it into it's components on the PHP side?

Comment: Write your java programm

Comment: I have the java program containing all my variables - I'm just not sure how I now pass them to an external php web service

Comment: @db579 Well, how *should* the data be sent? What *does* the service expect? JSON? Form-encoded? Query string? SOAP? GET/POST? Other?

Comment: That's the jist of my question really - What should the service expect and how should the Java program pass it. What is the simplest/best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an HTTP client e.g. this one.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html

and send a GET/POST request to your WebService.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Right. Not that POST would be very secure but it's slightly better.

Comment: Huh.. I thought `POST` would be sufficient.  My bad.

Comment: Why would post not be secure? Am I correct in thinking I want to pass my parameters using the .setParamter method of the URI builder?

Comment: @db579 Because the password flies in plaintext over the net anyway. So almost anybody can sniff/eavesdrop it.

Comment: @db579 If you want security recommendations, you will need to post another question probably :) I am not much of an expert on that part. I just have some basic knowledge.

Comment: Ah I see, my password is hashed and salted Java side and will be compared to a hashed and salted password in the database so I think POST should be fine?

Comment: Normally when you authenticate you don't send the hash to the server, you send the password and the servers salts/hashes it, and then compares with the stored DB data. Now, even if you send the hash, it is still not secure, because anyone who finds your hash will be able to login and issue more GET/POST requests just as you did i.e. on behalf of you. Given the scheme you propose, this hacker doesn't need to know your password once he got your hash. The hash is enough for him to take your identity and start making requests. I see no way you can make this secure over HTTP. You'll need HTTPS.